# What's the cleanest way to construct a Ruby array using a while loop?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Ruby has lots of nice ways of iterating and directly returning that result. This mostly involve array methods. For example:

```
def ten_times_tables
  (1..5).map { |i| i * 10 }
end

ten_times_tables # => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

However, I sometimes want to iterate using `while` and directly return the resulting array. For example, the contents of the array may depend on the expected final value or some accumulator, or even on conditions outside of our control.

A (contrived) example might look like:

```
def fibonacci_up_to(max_number)
  sequence = [1, 1]

  while sequence.last < max_number
    sequence << sequence[-2..-1].reduce(:+)
  end

  sequence
end

fibonacci_up_to(5) # => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

To me, this sort of approach feels quite "un-Ruby". The fact that I construct, name, and later return an array feels like an anti-pattern. So far, the best I can come up with is using `tap`, but it still feels quite icky (and quite nested):

```
def fibonacci_up_to(max_number)
  [1, 1].tap do |sequence|
    while sequence.last < max_number
      sequence << sequence[-2..-1].reduce(:+)
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone else have any cleverer solutions to this sort of problem?

Comment: Your contrived scenario is, as you say, quite unusual. So the code to achieve the result looks a little unusual too. But I don't see anything particularly wrong with your original approach, or any significant way to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something you might want to look into for situations like this (though maybe your contrived example fits this a lot better than your actual use case) is creating an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new), so your contrived example becomes:

From the docs for initialize:

> ```
> fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
>   a = b = 1
>   loop do
>     y << a
>     a, b = b, a + b
>   end
> end
> ```

and then call it:

```
p fib.take_while { |elem| elem <= 5 }
#=> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

So, you create an enumerator which iterates all your values and then once you have that, you can iterate through it and collect the values you want for your array in any of the usual Ruby-ish ways

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Simple Lime's Enumerator solution, you can write a method that wraps itself in an Enumerator:

```
def fibonacci_up_to(max_number)
  return enum_for(__callee__, max_number) unless block_given?

  a = b = 1
  while a <= max_number
    yield a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end

fibonacci_up_to(5).to_a # => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

This achieves the same result as returning an Enumerator instance from a method, but it looks a bit nicer and you can use the `yield` keyword instead of a `yielder` block variable. It also lets you do neat things like:

```
fibonacci_up_to(5) do |i|
  # ..
end
```